# Want to load first 10 div from one data role in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile just in learning stage I have created one File in which 5 data-role pages are there each data role page contain 30 divs,What I want is I want to load only 10 divs first,

When I click to html5 it loads html5 page 30 divs at a time I want 10 div to load first and on next click load another 10 divs 
here is **[fiddle]**(http://jsfiddle.net/pfxyLqLh/3/)
Structure is like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="html5">
<div class="div1">
</div>
<div class="div1">
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="div1">
</div>
</div> 
<div data-role="page" id="css">
<div class="div1">
</div>
<div class="div1">
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="div1">
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="jquery">
<div class="div1">
</div>
<div class="div1">
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="div1">
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to write simple jquery with

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#html5 .div1").slice(0, 10).each(function(index) {
    alert("dfdf");
});
});
</script>
```

But no success It would be great if anyone help me in this
Thanks

Comment: You need show first 10 divs remain are hidden ?

Comment: first 10 div should be visible and other will be hidden when I click on next button next 10 div will get loaded

Comment: What about this kind of divs id="css" ,id="jquery"

Comment: those are other data role pages let's take example
 I have 5 button on first page named html,css,jquery when i click on HTML it loads page-role with id html which contains 30 div and i need to show first 10 divs from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var i=2;// two show 2 box 
$("#html5 .div1").slice( i-2, i ).show();
i+=2;
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#html5 .div1").hide().slice( i-2, i ).show();
    i+=2;

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/obax02zr/6/)**

**NOTE:** I used 2 divs show only ,you have to change to 10

Comment: yes now you are showing 2 divs on click but what i want is to show 10 divs on load and next 10 divs when you click on click button and hide first 1 to 10 and show 11 to 20 div